# Appcelerator Titanium app integration Apple wallet

Tags: appcelerator-titanium, passbook, applepay, wallet

How is it possible to integrate `Apple Wallet` in an App developed in `Appcelerator Titanium`. This is to support the loyalty card program of an already existing app. I've searched for documentations a modules for this, with little success.

Appreciate if anyone could advise on this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is the [Ti.Passbook](https://github.com/appcelerator-archive/ti.passbook) module to handle the Passbook and included passes. And for Apple Pay, there is [Ti.ApplePay](https://marketplace.appcelerator.com/apps/68814?restoreSearch=true#!overview).